# Entity Framework with insert update delete multiple details

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a master table and a detail table.

In EF, at the update event, I want to update master. And with 3 details, I want to insert, delete and upload them. I use code like this:

```
//header
masterEntity.ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;

//1st detail 
detailEntity1.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
masterEntity.DetailEntities.Add(detailEntity1);

//2nd detail 
detailEntity2.ObjectState = ObjectState.Modified;
masterEntity.DetailEntities.Add(detailEntity2);

//3rd detail 
detailEntity3.ObjectState = ObjectState.Deleted;
masterEntity.DetailEntities.Add(detailEntity3);
```

By click Save button, sometimes I got the error.

What is the best practice for this case?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Every table must have it's own context and should be CRUDed separately